# Error en libreria jaxb-api.jar de glassfish 4.1.1

Tags: java, primefaces, netbeans-8.2, glassfish

Amigos tengo este error al compilar mi aplicación web:

> warning: [path] bad path element "C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules\jaxb-api.jar": no such file or directory
> warning: [path] bad path element "C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules\null": no such file or directory

Estoy usando netbeans 8.2 y glassfish 4.1.1 java versión "1.8.0_301"

He investigado y al parecer es la libreria jaxb-api.jar la del problema. La he descargado y añadido a las librerías y nada.

Al parecer este problema es el culpable de que no me funcione primeface en el proyecto.

Les agradecería su ayuda!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos ya logre solucionar uno de los errores. Descargue jaxb-api.jar de la web: "Descarga jaxb-api JAR 2.3.0 con todas las dependencias". Remplace el nombre jaxb-api JAR 2.3.0 por solo jaxb-api y la sobrescribí en la ruta: "C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules" donde se encuentra glassfish y listo.

Ahora solo me queda este error:
warning: [path] bad path element "C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules\null": no such file or directory

Si alguien me puede echar una mano se los agradecería.